# Les pronoms relatifs suivis d’un infinitif

Tags: formulation

J’ai vu pas mal de phrases du type

> Je veux un endroit où aller.

ou

> Je cherche un endroit où vivre.

Cet usage de l'infinitif est-il normal? Le trouve-t-on dans d'autres contextes grammaticaux ?

Comment: En anglais, par exemple, on ne dirait jamais « I want a place where live » mais plutôt « I want a place to live in ». Ce qui donnerait, en français « Je veux un endroit à vivre » qui a l’air fausse aussi. C’est pour cela que pose la question. Je sais qu’on peut détourner le problème en ajoutant un sujet « Je veux un endroit où je peux vivre »

Answer (score 3):

Oui, c'est un tour de phrase courant.

Avec d'autres pronoms relatifs :

> Tour d'horizon du pire voisin avec **lequel** voyager en avion. ([Le Point](https://www.lepoint.fr/insolite/les-pires-travers-des-passagers-en-avion-16-02-2015-1905303_48.php))
> mot à mot : *Overview of the worst neighbor with whom to fly* (*the worst neighbor to fly with*)

> Je n'ai pas un seul ami à **qui** parler. ([forum jeuxvideo.com](https://www.jeuxvideo.com/forums/42-51-63040998-1-0-1-0-je-n-ai-pas-un-seul-ami-a-qui-parler.htm))
> mot à mot : *I have not a single friend to (with) whom to talk.* (*a single friend to talk to*)

Le bon usage indique **§1117 R1 c)** (Propositions relatives, Le mode du verbe) :

> L'infinitif sans sujet est employé dans des cas où la relative
> implique l'idée de devoir ou de pouvoir :
> - *II ne vit point de paysan **à qui remettre le cheval*** (Stendhal, *La Chartreuse de Parme*, X).
> - *Je pourrai donc rencontrer des gens **à qui parler** en province*
> (Balzac, *Béatrix*, Pl., p. 12).
> - *Si M. de la Billardière et son fils viennent [au bal], il faut qu'ils trouvent **à qui parler*** (ID., *César Birotteau*, I, 7). É 3
> - *Il indique l'endroit **où pratiquer la plaie*** (J. De Pesquidoux, *Chez nous*, 1.1, p. 119).
> - *Il cherchait une main **à quoi s'accrocher*** (Farrère, *Civilisés*, XXX).
> - *Aucun visage **sur qui reposer les yeux** dans cette foule* (Mauriac, *Thérèse Desqueyroux*, p. 57).
> - *Le ministre [...] n'a point trouvé, dans son domaine, ses tombereaux d'or et les diamants de ses caves, une seule occasion **dont user*** (Saint Exupéry, *Citadelle*, CC).

Une note intéressante apparaît à la fin de cette liste de citations :

> Mais n'a-t-on pas, dans ces exemples, ou dans certains d'entre eux, la transformation d'une phrase interrogative ?

Comment: Mais dans les exemples ci-dessus « lequel, que, et quoi » ne sont-ils pas tous des pronoms interrogatifs? Alors que « où » est un pronom rélatif?

Comment: Ils sont interrogatifs, c'est vrai.

Comment: Tes exemples sont tous courants en anglais — *I don't know what to do, What to choose? Do you know which one to take?* Des exemples qui ne sont pas grammaticaux en anglais serait: *Is there a time when to meet, Is there a person who to ask.*

Comment: @PeterShor Oui, j'ai enlevé mes exemples car les pronoms n'y reprenaient pas un antécédent. Ils étaient interrogatifs. J'en ai remis un autre à la place avec cette fois j'espère, un vrai pronom relatif.

Comment: Overview of the worst neighbor with whom to fly. doesn't work.

Comment: @Lambie Are you trying to be helpful?

Comment: @User La similitude entre ton premier commentaire et la conclusion de Grevisse n'est-elle pas étonnante :-)

Comment: Ce n'est pas le sujet mais hormis le mot à mot, possiblement _to talk to ; to fly with_ sans pronom (_whom_) pour ces deux premiers exemples nous dit deepl. Je le dis simplement parce qu'il faut à mon avis accepter ces différences pour avoir les coudées franches.

Comment: @jlliagre Je suis désolé. J’ai un peu du mal à vous comprendre. Vous parlez duquel de mes commentaires? Celui que j’ai supprimé? La Grevisse c’est Le Bon Usage non? Vaut-il acheter ce livre? Comme vous l’avez dit j’ai l’impression que les répliques à chacune de mes questions en est tirée directement.

Comment: @User Je parle du premier commentaire à ma réponse (qui concernait son premier jet, modifié depuis): **Mais dans les exemples ci-dessus « lequel, que, et quoi » ne sont-ils pas tous des pronoms interrogatifs?** qui ressemble étonnamment à la conclusion du Bon usage: **Mais n'a-t-on pas, dans ces exemples, ou dans certains d'entre eux, la transformation d'une phrase interrogative ?**

Comment: Maurice Grevisse est l'auteur original du Bon usage. Cet ouvrage est en effet appelé aussi *Le Grevisse*. C'est incontestablement la meilleure grammaire française mais elle n'est pas donnée.

Comment: Je savais pas, je pensais que Le Grevisse c'était _Grammaire française_ (383 pp) mais je vois qu'ils appellent ça le Petit Grevisse ahahah. Là ils sont rendus aussi avec le Petit Bon usage hahaha, version courte (544 pp) du Bon usage (1750 pp), un tiers des pages pour 50% du prix. Curieux de voir. Le bon usage me fait _tripper_.

Comment: @λyoyed'oncques Pas de "bon petit usage" ou de "petit trésor" ;-) mais on a le petit Larousse, le petit Robert et, plus rare, le petit Littré.

Answer (score 1):

to as où in French:

- Je voudrais trouver une chaise où m'asseoir. =
- Je voudrais trouver une chaise pour m'asseoir.

Larousse

> [où](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/o%C3%B9/56842)

**Où et pour. On emploie parfois ***où à la place de pour*** : nous cherchons une salle où danser ; il ne reste pas une place où poser ses affaires.**

- Je voudrais un endroit pour poser mes affaires. ∝ où poser mes affaires.

Les mots pour et où dans ces exemples montrent une finalité. (Larousse: Caractère de ce qui tend à un but, à une fin ; ce but lui-même.)

**où** where, an adverb or a relative pronoun.

But the point here is this: When **to** in English means for the purpose of, as in your two examples: Je cherche une endroit où aller/où vivre. (looking for a place to live in/looking for a place to go where the meaning is for the purpose of living there, for the purpose of going there), that is **to** plus infinitive in English and can be **pour** or **où** in French.

Comment: L'accent va dans l'autre sens en montant : ← pas →.

Comment: Ce n'est pas la question, à peine un détail concernant l'usage de l'infinitif dans les relatives. voilà le titre : « Les pronoms relatifs suivis d’un infinitif »; **Les** pronoms relatifs, pas « où » ; vous ne dites que deux ou trois mots à propos de  « où ».

Comment: Vous faite une assertion que le Larousse ne fait pas ; « Les mots pour et oú dans ces exemples montrent une finalité » . Non, le Larousse ne dit pas ça  ; « où » ne peut pas indiquer une finalité.

Comment: Je cherche une chaise pour m'asseoir/oú m'asseoir ne montrent pas une finalité? C'est le but de l'opération du verbe chercher, non?

Comment: Dans le mot même « pour », oui, il y a une notion de finalité, mais en ce qui concerne » où » c'est le lieu, sans notion de but.

Comment: Il n'y a dans ces deux usages qu'une coïncidence qui permet de traiter la connection entre « endroit » et « vivre » soit selon une relation de but soit selon une relation de lieu. Il se trouve que le résultat est le même. Cependant cela ne va pas plus loin, et, de plus, « endroit pour vivre » n'est pas du très bon français.

Comment: Un peu tiré par les cheveux, ce que tu dis lá puisque selon le Larousse le sens est le même pour les deux.

Comment: Non, où sont ces mots qui disent que le sens est le même ?

Comment: endroit pour m'asseoir et endroit oú m'asseoir, c'est bonnet blanc, blanc bonnet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130337/discussion-between-lph-and-lambie).

Comment: @LPH The Larousse definition implies they have the same meaning. Come on. Otherwise, they would explain another meaning and they do not explain any other meaning.,

Answer (score 1):

Les explications suivantes sont tirées de [Guide de grammaire française pour étudiant finnophones • Jean-Michel Kalmbach](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/tdm.html). Certains principes de l'utilisation du mode dans les relatives permettent de mieux comprendre l'usage de ce type de relative.

> [Le mode du ver­be de la re­la­ti­ve](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/relatives.html#611)
>
> Le mode ha­bi­tu­el du ver­be de la pro­po­si­tion re­la­ti­ve est l’in­di­ca­tif. Il y a quelques cas où le ver­be peut être au sub­jonc­tif ou à l’in­fi­ni­tif.
>
> **Subjonctif**
>
> On uti­li­se le sub­jonc­tif dans une re­la­ti­ve spé­ci­fian­te pour ex­pri­mer une nuance de but ou de con­sé­quence (quel­que chose doit être tel qu’on puisse faire…).
>
> ■ Je cherche un livre qui *soit* facile à lire.
> ■ Il fau­drait quel­qu’un qui *connaisse* bien la musique classique.
> ■ Ils n’ont pas trouvé de séjour *qui* leur convienne.
> ■ Pour les vacances, j’ai­merais aller quel­que part où il ne *fasse* pas trop chaud.
> ■ Il n’a rien trouvé qui lui *plaise*.
>
> **Indicatif**
>
> S’il n’y a pas de nuance de but, on uti­li­se l’in­di­ca­tif :
>
> ■ Je connais quel­qu’un qui *veut* garder des enfants le mercredi.
> ■ J’ai trouvé un ap­par­te­ment qui me **permet** de recevoir plus de monde.
>
> Dans la langue cou­rante et dans le fran­çais parlé, il est assez fré­quent qu’on n’u­ti­li­se pas le sub­jonc­tif, mê­me s’il y a une nuance de but :
>
> ■ Je ne vois rien qui me plait.
> ■ On n’a trouvé personne qui avait les qualifications né­ces­saires.
>
> **Infinitif**
>
> À la place du sub­jonc­tif, quand l’an­té­cé­dent in­dé­fi­ni de la re­la­ti­ve spé­ci­fian­te est pré­cé­dé d’une pré­po­si­tion et que le su­jet de la prin­ci­pa­le est le mê­me que celui de la re­la­ti­ve (co­ré­fé­ren­ce du su­jet), on peut aus­si uti­li­ser l’infinitif :
>
> ■ Elle n’avait personne à qui *raconter* ses soucis. (= Elle n’avait personne à qui elle puisse raconter ses soucis.)
> ■ Il ne connait personne en qui *avoir* confiance. (= Il ne connait personne en qui il puisse avoir confiance.)
> ■ Il cherchait un endroit calme où [= dans lequel] *passer* ses vacances. (= Il cherchait un endroit calme où il puisse passer ses vacances.)
> ■ Il lui faudrait quel­qu’un sur qui se *reposer*. (=Il lui faudrait quel­qu’un sur qui il puisse se reposer.)
>
> Les re­la­ti­ves in­fi­ni­tives s’em­ploient surtout dans le code écrit après des ver­bes exprimant le but com­me *chercher, avoir besoin de, falloir* etc. (« elle n’avait personne à qui …» signifie « elle avait besoin de quel­qu’un à qui …»), mais aus­si dans le fran­çais parlé dans des ex­pres­sions plus ou moins figées com­me les suivantes
> •  *on ne sait plus à qui se fier*
> •  *on ne sait plus qui croire*
> • *je ne sais que dire* ».

*Les explications suivantes sont dues à user LPH, et ne peuvent pas prétendre cerner la totalité du sujet.*

Ce qu'il est important de retenir ci-dessus c'est que l'on utilise l'infinitif lorsque les conditions suivantes sont réunies :
1/ on veut exprimer la même nuance que  le subjonctif sert à introduire,
2/ la principale et la proposition relative ont le même sujet,
3/ l'antécédent est indéfini (un pronom indéfini, un syntagme nominal dont le déterminant est indéfini (un, des, plusieurs, … )), et, de plus,
4/ le pronom est précédé d'une préposition (exception : « où », parce que « où » est équivalent à « dans lequel », « dans quoi », … dans lesquel se trouve la préposition « dans » (**en qui, à qui, sur qui, …**). Il y a au moins une exception et dans ce cas le déterminant *défini* permet un certain sens (considéré dans un exemple ci-dessous).

- Le restaurant où manger lorsque vous êtes dans ce quartier c'est le Coq d'Or. (*La combinaison de l'article défini et de l'infinitif confèrent à la phrase la signification spéciale suivante : le restaurant dont on parle est un endroit exceptionnel du point de vue de la qualité de la nourriture qui y est servie.*)
- Lorsque vous êtes dans ce quartier, le Coq d'Or est le restaurant où manger. (*alternative à la construction précédente, sans changement de sens*)
- Il existe *plusieurs* abris **où** se réfugier.
- Il ne voit pas (*ce*) sur **quoi** faire des modifications.
- C'est *quelque chose* sur **quoi** compter.

On trouve la relative avec un verbe à l'infinitif aussi dans un autre contexte grammatical, celui  où le pronom n'a pas d'antécédent. Elle peut alors avoir la fonction de *sujet* ou de  *cod* pour chacun des pronoms avec laquelle il est possible de la construire.

- À **Qui** donner le poste n'est que votre affaire. (*sujet*)
- À **qui** decerner le prix est décidé par un commité. (*sujet*)
- Un commité décide à **qui** décerner le prix. (*cod*)
- On lui a montré à **qui** donner de l'aide en cas d'urgence. (*cod*)
- Il ne sait pas **où** aller. (*cod*)
- **Où** aller n'est pas la question, la question pour nous c'est comment y aller. (*sujet*)
- Qui sait sur **quoi** compter ?
- Ils n'ont  plus de **quoi** écrire.
- Ce dans **quoi** investir peu être déterminé en partie au moyen d'un index boursier.

Comment: Dis-moi, comment ta réponse explique utilisation du **où** pour **pour**?

Comment: @Lambie Il me semble que ce n'est pas la question ; ce qui est demandé c'est « est-ce que c'est normal ? », et je donne des conditions dans lesquelles c'est normal. Il n'est question de « pour » nulle part ; je viens de vérifier les commentaires.  Où vivre/pour vivre ? ces deux sens n'ont rien à voir l'un avec l'autre.

Comment: Both those sentences can take pour or oú. It does not require a thesis-long argument going into the subjunctive etc. It just does not. It's just oú or pour plus infinitive. Lis le commentaire. Le OP ne savait pas que où et pour ont un rapport ici avec l'infinitif et avec to live in.  a chair to sit in, a place to live (in), an office to work in: à ou pour en français.

Comment: Non ! On ne dit pas « un endroit pour aller » et la forme  « où aller » est inclue dans la question, ce qui montre encore que c'est une question à propos des pronoms et non pas une question restreinte à « où ».